# C# DateTime.Tostring(), period instead of colon, regardless or provided format

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring

I'm suddenly having problems with the C# DateTime.ToString() method which I have never seen before. I'm working on a project which was working just fine before the weekend and now come Monday, all my DateTime strings are with periods instead of colons (i.e. **2020-12-14 13:45:33** becomes **2020-12-14 13.45.33**).

I'm using this format string "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" when creating strings from my DateTime objects and it has always worked for me, but now this... What is going on?

This just happened over night and I have no idea as to why...

Anyone has an idea to why this is happening and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** to answer a few questions in comments - I live in Denmark, OS is Windows 10 x64, framework is .NET 4.7.2.

**EDIT 2:** I have fixed my problem for now by adding a section to the web.config of my web application, but I still have no idea why this is suddenly required from one day to the other.

I added the following to the system.web section of the web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="da-DK" />
```

The *uiCulture* isn't important in this case, but the **culture="en-US"** changed the dots back to colons in the time part of the datetime strings as I needed them to be and my web application is back to running normally again...

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? What OS are you running on? What country do you live in?

Comment: See also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb926074-d593-4e0b-8754-7026acc607ec/datetime-tostring-colon-replaced-with-period?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: The symbols in a format specifier aren't *literal* symbols; they're *tokens* that are placeholders for the *actual* value as specified in the `CultureInfo`. It sounds like you're using a culture where the `.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator` is period rather than colon, so: check which culture is configured, or: specify an explicit culture in your code if you want to override the ambient one. A quick test shows that the following cultures use `"."` as the time separator: as
as-IN
da
da-DK
da-GL
en-DK
en-FI
fi
fi-FI
id
id-ID
kl
kl-GL
si
si-LK
smn
smn-FI

Comment: If you want to specify that it should become a dot regardless of the culture, [escape them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals): `HH\\.mm\\.ss`.

Comment: Updated question with some more info as per request. Also I do not want a dot, I'm getting a dot instead of colon - From one day to the other this has changed throughout my entire app...

Comment: Probably something in Windows 10 was changed. I usually do this if I want to specify the exact datetime rendering regardless of what the computers regional setting is:
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: You can escape the seperator to become what you want, fx as you prefer colon I suggest to use the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss`